# Count Negative in Range

Tags: google-sheets, countif

I am attempting to count the number of occurrences that contain a `*` in a specific numeric range using the `COUNTIFS` function in Google Sheets. The function works for a positive range, but fails when I add a negative. I have tried escaping the negative and adding parens but nothing seems to work.

Works - correctly returns a value of 1, because 0.01* is between 0 and .1 and contains an `*`

```
0.01*
.8*
*
-0.08
-0.08*
=COUNTIFS(J62:J66, ">0.000\*",J62:J66, "<0.1\*")
```

Does Not Work - expected return value of 1, because -.08* is between 0 and -.1 and contains an `*`.

```
-.3*
-.8*
-*
-0.08
-0.08*
=COUNTIFS(H62:H66, ">-0.1\*",H62:H66, "<0.000\*")
```

**edit to address @pnuts comment**

If I change `-.3*` to `-0.3*` and `-.8*` to `-0.8*` the function returns a value of 2, which is not what I expect.

Comment: Thanks for catching that. Should make more sense now that I fixed the explanation for why the first one work.

Comment: Good question! See edit added at end of post.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is ***NOT*** the negative ranges. The problem is simply the * part.

> Works - correctly returns a value of 1, because 0.01* is between 0 and .1 and contains an *

```
   0.01*
   .8*
    *
    -0.08
    -0.08*
   =COUNTIFS(J62:J66, ">0.000\*",J62:J66, "<0.1\*")
```

This doesn't work. It gives you 1 ONLY because of the 4th entry -0.08 without the `*`. This satisfies `J62:J66, "<0.1\*"`, but not `J62:J66, ">0.000\*".` Hence a Total of 1 is arrived. To test, Simply change only this fourth number to `-0.08*`and you won't get 1. This is NOT `because 0.01* is between 0 and .1 and contains an *`

You cannot use `*` in a countif. Simply replace the `*` and `COUNTIF` will work splendidly.

```
       B1 =ARRAYFORMULA(--REGEXREPLACE(T(A1:A5),"\*",""))
```

This will remove the `*` from all your text and put it in helper column B. There will be errors for those without the `*` . But that's fine, since you only want to count those numbers with * in it. Now simply use `COUNTIF` on the B column.

Answer (score -1):

```
        = ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIFS(ROUND(--REGEXEXTRACT(T(A1:A5),"((?:\+|\-){0,1}(?:\d+){0,5}(?:\.\d+))(?:\*)"),2),">0.0",ROUND(--REGEXEXTRACT(T(A1:A5),"((?:\+|\-){0,1}(?:\d+){0,5}(?:\.\d+))(?:\*)"),2),"<=0.8"))
```

This should works. Problems with your original formula is: You can't use text as numbers. Numbers should be extracted from text and counted.

Comment: @dementedpenguin Check this formula. This should work for negative ranges

Comment: It works for positive numbers, but not negative which is what I'm stuck on. Thanks for the suggestion @anonymous!

Comment: This works for negative ranges too...... `= ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIFS(ROUND(--REGEXEXTRACT(T(A1:A5),"((?:\+|\-){0,1}(?:\d+){0,5}(?:\.\d+))(?:\*)"),2),">-0.1",ROUND(--REGEXEXTRACT(T(A1:A5),"((?:\+|\-){0,1}(?:\d+){0,5}(?:\.\d+))(?:\*)"),2),"<0"))` `-.3*
-.8*
-*
-0.08
-0.08*` Returns 1 as expected by you.